# I have created a multithreaded java application which outputs to the console, but I want it to output to textfields in a GUI.

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I have tried various methods to get the threads to start and output to the console but nothing has worked so far. I have a main method called BankAccount which contains the threads, created using executor service. I tried using the method:

```
public void run() {
        // Updating of textboxes 
        jTextField22.setText(BankMain.executorService);
    }
});
```

But this did not work, I was searching and found something about async and sync methods but not enough explanation on this exact problem. I wasn't sure if using the Executor service instead of threads with a timer would work for printing to the GUI? I also wanted the threads to stop at after 52 seconds, when I entered 52.seconds it did not work. Code for my threads:

```
final BankAccount accountBalance = new BankAccount(0);
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    //print balance  - monthly
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Statement(accountBalance), 0, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //income - monthly
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Incomming("Wage", 2000, 4000, accountBalance), 0, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Incomming("Interest", 10, 4000, accountBalance), 0, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //rent - monthly
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Consumables("Oil Bill", 250, 3000, accountBalance), 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //

    //food - weekly
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Consumables("Food Bill", 60, 1000, accountBalance), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Consumables("Electricity Bill", 50, 1000, accountBalance), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Consumables("Entertainment Bill", 400, 1000, accountBalance), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Consumables("Shoppping Bill", 200, 1000, accountBalance), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //shutdown after a 52 secs
    executorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            accountBalance.getBalance();
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *"I wasn't sure if using the Executor service instead of threads with a timer would work for printing to the GUI?"*  That's actually not a question.  OTOH I would not use a normal `Thread` to update the GUI, but the Event Dispatch Thread.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). As it stands, I find your question incomprehensible.

Comment: My main question is how to output the threads to the textfields on my GUI. And when I said _"I wasn't sure if using the Executor service instead of threads with a timer would work for printing to the GUI?"_ I meant to type a full stop not a question mark sorry. Is there anyway you could help me on the main question?

Answer (score 0):

Output to UI from multiple threads should be wrapped inside `Runnable`s. You currently launch `Runnable`s to do some work but the result should be posted in separate `Runnable`s and added to the Event Dispatching Thread (the UI thread) with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. I would do it like this...

```
class Consumables implements Runnable /* or TimerTask or other implementor of Runnable */
{
  public void run()
  {
    // Do your work here
    String result = doTheWork();

    // Post results
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PrintTask(result));
  }
}

private class PrintTask implements Runnable
{
  private final String mResult;

  public PrintTask(int result)
  {
    mResult = result;
  }

  public void run()
  {
    jTextField22.setText(mResult);
  }
}
```